# How can I unlock my screen when my input is in a different language?

Tags: screen-lock, input-source, password

I have 3 languages installed and everytime my MacBook goes to sleep - the screen is being locked. After entering a password, system says that it's incorrect. It appears, that I'm entering password not in English language, but in Lithuanian (mother tongue), where all digits are taken by Lithuanian-specific vowels and consonants (from 1 to 8: ąčęėįšųū). And the problem is that I can't change language back to English so that I'd be able to enter digits for my password. Using backtick for "default language" does not work (I get beeps all the time). Copy pasting does not work too.

Any suggestions? As I don't think I need to take care of what language my MacBook locks the screen in.

I'm running Mac OS X 10.6.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to System Preferences > Accounts > Login Options and tick "Show input menu in login window" you'll then be able to change it in the screen saver password window as well

In OS X 10.7 Lion, "Accounts" is called "Users & Groups".  The setting "Show input menu in login window" really ought to be active by default when plural language input sources are enabled, though.

Answer (score 1):

If you used before lithuania language and with this language locked screen.then you must to press in one time     ctrl and alt plius number which for you need.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **System preferences > Language & Text**  and in the **Language** tab move your password language (in your case, English) on top of the other languages.

Answer (score 0):

just turn it on and turn it on again and it will go back to english i just did it