# I cannot log in due to changed keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard, login-screen

My (Danish) keyboard on my 2016 MacBook Pro has changed layout after crashing. My password contains a pipe charecter but this cannot be accessed via the normal way (alt + i) or the US Way (alt + 7).

How can I determine the keyboard layout or change it without logging in? It would also help if I could type in a non password input field to test. Is this possible?

Comment: The US way for | is not Alt 7, but Shift \ (or Shift ' on a Danish printed keyboard)

Answer (score 3):

**Method 1:** Go into the Guest User(if it is there) and change the language.

**Method 2:** See [Mac os X - locked outside my account (language!)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/8810/mac-os-x-locked-outside-my-account-language).

**Method 3:** Try booting into recovey mode(holding <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> at boot). Then you should be able to change the keyboard layout(in the menu bar).

**Method 4:** See https://superuser.com/q/871277.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting my mac in safe mode 4 or 5 times solved the issue for me.

Reason: When restarting in safe mode, mac clears all the font cache and setting.